# partition gets disappear while mounting

Tags: ubuntu-12.04

im using ubuntu 12.04 I created 4 partition in ext4 and one in ext3. I can see all the partition in computer but whenever I try to mount partition I used to click on the partition it supposes to get mount but now its getting disappear from the computer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try command line tools like `fdisk` and `mount`

Try this:

1. check whether you still have those partitions:

   ```
   fdisk /dev/sda
   ```

   `/dev/sda` replace by your hard disk, inside program write `p`, program will output all the partitions on your hard drive, exit `fdisk` by pressing `q`
2. mount the partition:

   ```
   mount /dev/sda3 /mnt/something
   ```

   sda3 replace by your partition and /mnt/something by dir where you'd like to have the partition mounted.

Most likely, your graphical program (you didn't mention name) stopped working for some reason. Command lines works well and something goes wrong some error/warning will be outputted

Comment: I resolved it by debugging the filesystem, thank you for your suggestion xhudik.

Comment: and what was the problem?